# odbc package in R throwing caught segfault error while connecting to Oracle Database

Tags: r, oracle, odbc

I am trying to connect to oracle database using odbc package in R and while connecting it is throwing caught segfault and we are unable to connect to database. Please find the details mentioned below and we have configured unixodbc configuration in the server but with RODBC package, we are able to establish the connection.

> library(odbc)
>   Target2Conn<-dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "PEGA_DEV", uid = "username", pwd = "username_123")

*** caught segfault ***
address 0x38, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:

1:

```
odbc_connect(connection_string, timezone = timezone, timezone_out = timezone_out,     encoding = encoding, bigint = bigint, timeout = timeout)
```

2:

```
OdbcConnection(dsn = dsn, ..., timezone = timezone, timezone_out = timezone_out,     encoding = encoding, bigint = bigint, timeout = timeout,     driver = driver, server = server, database = database, uid = uid,     pwd = pwd, dbms.name = dbms.name, .connection_string = .connection_string)
```

3: `.local(drv, ...)`

4:

```
dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "PEGA_DEV", uid = "username", pwd = "username_123")
```

5:

```
dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "PEGA_DEV", uid = "username", pwd = "username_123")
```

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection

Comment: shouldnt it be `odbc::dbConnect`?

Comment: if we use odbc::dbConnect, we are getting below mentioned error.
> Target2Conn<-dbConnect(odbc::dbConnect, dsn = "PEGA_DEV", uid = "username", pwd = "username_123")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature ‘"standardGeneric"’

Comment: `Target2Conn<-dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "PEGA_DEV", uid = "username", pwd = "username_123")`